# Error when Searching trees iterively

Tags: python, data-structures, typeerror

I need to search a tree by checking if the sum of the branches from a node is greater than zero. However, I'm running into a problem with the sum - I get a type error (int object is not callable) on the

```
branch_sum = [t[0] for t in current]
```

line. I thought it was because eventually I'll get a single node

```
current = [[1,'b']]
```

(for example), and so I added the if/else statement. I.e. I thought that I was trying to sum something that looked like this:

```
first = [1]
```

However, the problem still persists. I'm unsure of what could be causing this.

For reference, current is a list of lists, with the first slot is the node data the second slot is a node id (in the inner list). The group() function groups the data on a node based on the id of the sub-nodes (left subnodes have ids beginning with 1, right have ids beginning with 0).

The tree I'm searching is stored as a list of lists like:

```
tree = [[0, '1'], [1,'01'], [0,'001']]
```

i.e. it's a set of Huffman Codes.

```
from collections import deque 

def group(items):
    right = [[item[0],item[1][1:]] for item in items if item[1].startswith('1')]
    left  = [[item[0],item[1][1:]] for item in items if item[1].startswith('0')]

    return left, right

def search(node):
    loops = 0
    to_crawl = deque(group(node))
    while to_crawl:
        current = to_crawl.popleft() # this is the left branch of the tree
        branch_sum = 0
        if len(current)==1:
            branch_sum = sum([t for t in current])
        else: 
            branch_sum = sum([t[0] for t in current])
        if branch_sum !=0 :
            l,r = group(current)
            to_crawl.extendleft(r)
            to_crawl.extendleft(l)
        loops += 1
    return loops
```

Here's what I'm trying to do:

GIven a tree, with a lot of the data being 0, find the 1. To do this, split the tree into two branches (via the group() function) and push onto deque. Pop a branch off the deque, then sum the data in the branch. If the sum is not zero split the branch into two sub branches, push the sub branches onto the deque. Keep on doing this until I've found the non-zero datum. I should end up with a single item of the form [1,'101'] in the deque when I exit.

Comment: Can you show us your `group` function? as it seems to be important for the structure of the `to_crawl` variable.

Comment: Added, but I think the problem is more localised than that.

Comment: Could you give us the code for the tree itself? I mean, its a little hard for us to debug the problem if we do not have the class and the use-case. Also, is there a traceback?

Comment: Are you sure that the error msg says "int object is not callable" and not "'int' object is not ITERABLE"?

Comment: @JohannesCharra yes, sorry I was in a rush to get to a meeting.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac added an example of the tree. If a codeword begins with a 0 it's a right branch, 1 a left branch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly assume that the error says

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

because you end up passing a 2-tuple as `node` to

```
to_crawl = deque(group(node))
```

which gives you a 2-element deque. Then

```
current = to_crawl.popleft()
```

gives you a single element (an integer) as `current`. This is clearly not iterable, which leads to the given error.

Side note: For brevity, you can use sum like this

```
sum(current)
```

instead of

```
sum([x for x in current])
```

Comment: why wouldn't len(current) throw an 'int has no len()' error if I popleft() an int?

Comment: What I want to do is keep on popping and pushing the branches of the tree onto the deque until there is only a single [0,'101'] in the deque, then exit the loop. As it's written here it'll continue poping once it has reached this case.